# How to merge two unallocated partitions which 1st is on left site and 2nd is on right side

Tags: linux, partition, gparted, resize2fs

[image]

This is how it looks. I wonder if it's possible to merge the 2 unallocated partitions without data loss

Comment: What have  you tried to acomplish your goal?

Comment: Have you consider using a tool like `gparted`?

Comment: In short, yes, it's possible. Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` to your question.